# How to Convert English alphabet in a string to its ASCII value in java while using stream API?

Tags: java, java-stream

For example, I have a string `String str = "a_B_c"`, and How to Convert English alphabet in the string to its ASCII value in java while using stream API? Like the result of `String str = "a_B_c"` is `97_66_99`.

I just want to know if this can be done by using java stream api, I will be really appreciate if you post your answer, thx.

Comment: Are those underscore *always* between letters?

Comment: This problem seems awfully ill-suited for streams...

Comment: Yeah, it's not suitable for streams, thx all of you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you'd have to stream the string's individual characters. You certainly can. It's unlikely to be particularly nice or efficient; streams are a tool. Writing code presupposing tools is a bad idea. You're asking the equivalent of: "I have some bread and some schmear. I need to put the schmear on the bread. I just bought this shiny new clawhammer, so, I would prefer to use it for this task!".

You *can* smear a slice of bread with a clawhammer, if you must. It's a bit awkward, though. Is using streams for this as bad? Maybe - but the point is: Don't presuppose tools. Bread is best smeared with a butter knife. If you have one in your drawer than use it.

There's a somewhat (?) common belief that 'streams just make everything better'. That's patently false. It makes things that are well suited to streams a lot better. It usually makes the rest a lot worse, by being non-transparent on various fronts (local mutable variables, exceptions, and control flow), and being less flexible.

You're in luck, here. It's a wash, mostly - this is about as easy with streams as with a for loop.

```
"a_B_c".chars()
  .mapToObj(x -> x == '_' ? "" : String.valueOf(x))
  .collect(Collectors.joining("_"));
```

or possibly:

```
Arrays.stream("a_B_c".split("_"))
  .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
  .collect(Collectors.joining("_"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem/question correctly, you can do this:

```
String str = "a_B_c";
String[] letters = str.split("_");
Stream<String> letterStream = Arrays.stream(letters);
```

And then use `Stream.map` to convert the letters to their char code. And afterwards use `Collectors.joining("_")` to rebuild the String.

This of course only works correctly if there's only a single letter between each underscore.

Comment: Yeah, it works, thank you^_^

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do the job:

```
private static String foo(String str) {
    return str.chars().mapToObj(value -> value == "_".charAt(0) ? "_" : "" + value).collect(Collectors.joining( "" ));
}
```